# How to add class on first record in array using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I am working in Reactjs and using Nextjs,I am trying to add class(active) on
"first id"/array first record (fetching from db) but right now working with statically "where id=1" instead of First record,How can i do this ? in other words i want to add active on "first record(in array)" not "where id=1",
I tried with following code

```
{this.state.trending.map((post, index) => {
      return (
                <>
                <div className={`carousel-item ${post.id == 1 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
            )
       })}
```

Comment: why don't you use index instead of post.id ,
like this : <div className={`carousel-item ${index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}>

Comment: [Does this answer your Q ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74471417/how-to-conditionaly-add-class-in-reactjs/74471465#74471465)

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` instead of `post.id`. Compare it to `0` instead of `1` and you should be just fine.

```
this.state.trending.map((post, index) => (
  <div className={`carousel-item ${index === 0 ? 'active' : ''}`}>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.state.trending.map((post, index) => (
  <div className={"carousel-item"+((index == 0)? 'active':'')}>
)
```